# Polynomials as functions in R

Tags: r, function, loops, polynomials

Sorry in advance if the question is stupid/was answered somewhere else/... I could not find any nice solution.

Based on the idea of power series I have

A) a vector of real coefficients of lengths n which comes from an other loop and which can be rather long, but lets assume it is simple, for instance,

```
a<-1:10
```

and

B) a real center, e.g.

```
c<-3
```

I would like to define the polynomial (in my example)

```
a[1]+a[2]*(x-3)+ a[3]*(x-3)^2+ .... + a[10]*(x-3)^9
```

as a function. Unfortunately

1) the function `as.polynomial(a)` only allows center 0 (as far as I understand) so I cannot use it and

2) the list of coefficients can be long, too long to do it by hand

3) I might later ever need a multivariable version.

I would prefer to use a loop to define this "finite power series" but I do not know how loops and sums of functions can be realized in a clean fashion (and I did not find it either).

Something like (very naive)

`t<-function(x) 0
for(i in 1:length(a)) 
{t<-function(x) {t(x) + a[i]*(x-c)^(i-1}}`

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

i think this works

```
my_polynomial = function(x) {
  sum(sapply(seq_along(a), function(ii) a[ii] * (x - c) ^ (ii - 1L)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. Unfortunately (sorry for not mentioning this earlier) I also want to plot this function (using ggplot) - and even if the definition of this function seems great ggplot gives me errors (using `stat_function`) - any ideas?

Comment: Most likely it will work if you replace the `sum` with `cumsum`. Be careful to specify `n` to be the same as the number of points in the data frame when calling `stat_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the future reference. To change the center using the package polynom use `change.origin`

For example:

```
change.origin(as.polynomial(a),3)
```